# Number of zeros in the critical strip and complex argument

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

According to the Wikipedia article on Riemann hypothesis,

> The number of zeros of the zeta function with imaginary part between $0$ and $T$ is given by
> $$N(T)=\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{Arg}\left(\xi\left(\frac{1}{2}+iT\right)\right)$$
> where $\xi$ is Riemann's xi function and **the argument is defined by varying it continuously along the line with $\Im (s)=T$, starting with argument $0$ at $\infty+iT$.**

What exactly does "varying it continuously along, [...] starting with [...]" mean? I have no idea but I know the definition of the *prinicpal complex argument*, how are these arguments related?

Comment: do you know about analytic continuation on a curve? outside of zeroes (where we need to cut out some stuff), $\log \xi$ can be analytically continued on curves, so in particular $\arg \xi =\Im \log \xi$ can be done so - here we start at large $\sigma$ and continue it on segments to the left; note that here we need to avoid the $t$ where $\xi$ has zeroes with ordinate $t$ as there the argument jumps, so is discontinuous - one can, of course, define it either as a limit from above say, or as the average below and above and get a well-defined function which has jumps at the zeroes;

Comment: @Conrad What does "we start at large $\sigma$ and continue it on segments to the left" mean? In mathematical symbols? I don't doubt it's understandable for someone but I still don't get it.

Comment: @Conrad Do you know any books where I can find the formula from Wikipedia?

Comment: Any book about RZ or ANT should have it - for example Titchmarsh RZ book; usually the argument of zeta (or xi) is defined a little differently starting from $\arg \zeta (2)=0$ and going on the vertical line up to $T$ and then on the horizontal line to $-\infty$ (again assuming $T$ is not a zero ordinate) as the formulas are easy to deduce this way, but starting from positive infinity doesn;t change things much

Comment: @Conrad What page is it in Titchmarsh's book?

Comment: page 212 - section 9.3 has the proof of Riemann von Mangoldt formula for the zeroes of zeta precisely this way, though he uses the defintion of the argument starting from $2$ as noted above

Comment: @Conrad Titschmarsh uses $\Delta$ (called "variation"). I've never seen the "variation" concept before. What books would you recommend for me so that I can understand that concept he is using?

Comment: The $\Delta$ notation related to the argument principal is discussed in some of the comments on the answers to [this Math StackOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/407392).

Comment: In general $\Delta_{\gamma} \arg f=\int_\gamma f'(z)dz/f(z)$ is just the change in the argument of $f$ when $f$ traverses curve $\gamma$ expressed quantitatively as an integral (assuming as usual that $f$ is analytic and non zero in a neighborhood of $\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is a nice eg rectifiable curve); the argument principle relates this quantity to the number of zeroes (and poles) of $f$ "inside" $\gamma$ when the curve is Jordan and $f$ is analytic (meromorphic) on a neighborhood of $\gamma \cup \text {int} \gamma$